How does one draw the Penrose diagram for an FLRW universe with three different epochs?
Let's model the universe with the FLRW metric
$$ ds^2 =-dt^2 +a(t)^2\big(d\chi +R_k(\chi)^2 d\Omega^2\big)$$
where $a(t)$ is the scale factor and $R_k(\chi)$ is $\chi$ for a spatially flat ($k=0$) spacetime, equal to $\sin(\chi)$ for a spacetime with positive spatial curvature ($k=1$) and equal to $\sinh(\chi)$  for a spacectime with negative spatial curvature ($k=-1$).
If there's only one component in the universe (matter, radiation or dark energy), we get
$$ a(t)=\begin{cases}t^{2/3}\ \  \text{ for matter}\\ t^{1/2}\ \  \text{ for radiation}\\ e^{Ht}\ \ \  \text{for dark energy}\end{cases}$$
Now, let's consider the conformal Penrose diagram of each universe. I understand that both matter and radiation dominated universes start with a Big bang and have a future null infinity. On the other hand, the dark energy dominated universe is eternal and has no null boundary; its conformal diagram is that of a de Sitter spacetime (i.e. a box with only asymtptotic future and past spacelike boundaries but no boundaries "on the sides").
I understand that the universe started being radiation dominated, then switched to matter dominated and currently is (and forever after will be) dark energy dominated.
My question is: How are we supposed to glue the different conformal diagrams? Is there a way to make an actual, realistic conformal diagram of the universe as it switches through each era? Does it even make sense to talk about an asymptotic boundary for the first eras of the universe? if the asymptotic region is supposed to be the place where things go after an infinite time, it doesn't matter if radiation shot to infinity during the radiation dominated era, by the time it "gets there" the universe will have become dark energy dominated so there will be no null boundary.
My guess is that the conformal diagram of our universe should look like the dark energy dominated diagram, but with a Big bang in the beginning, which should be the only noticeable difference. It doesn't matter that there would be a null future infinity during matter/radiation dominace, because in the far future the universe is dark energy dominated and there is no null future infinity anyways.
P.S.: Side question, does the value of $k$ affect the conformal diagram at all?

About the side question: yes, the value of $k$ changes the conformal diagram.  For $\Lambda = 0$, it's half a diamond for $k = 0$ and for $k = -1$, with the Big Bang singularity at the bottom (spacelike zig-zag on the diagram).  For $k = +1$ (spatially closed), it's a simple square for the radiation model (with a Big Bang and a Big Crunch zig-zag at bottom and top of the square), and it's a twice height rectangle for the $k = +1$ dust-matter model, with zig-zags at bottom and top.  The empty deSitter diagram is an horizontal rectangle for all values of $k = 0, \pm 1$.

About the glue process, I'm no expert on this, but I have seen the deSitter rectangle tilted by 45 degrees and glued on the open ($k = 0$) radiation half-diamond, in some papers.  I even saw many of these diagrams simply piled and glued together with 45 degrees angles, one on top of another.

Hi! thanks for your comments. I have a couple of questions. 1) Is there a reference where I could see this? I have a few cosmology books but  none care too much about conformal diagrams. 2) What would be the meaning of "twice height" in a conformal diagram? The length is rather arbitrary, only the shape of the boundary matters (I think!). 3) I don't think I understand the process of "tilting the deSitter rectangle by 45  degrees". Is it an actual tilting in the sense that the boundaries are now null? Or is it simply an "aesthetic" tilting to glue both spacetimes?

What I mean by "aesthetic" is that even if you tilt the de Sitter diagram, you also tilt its axis so that the spacelike boundaries stay spacelike and the timelike poles (the vertical lines on the left and the right) remain timelike. As opposed to a more "physical", "real" tilting where you keep the lightocones straight but tilt the diagram, thus making all sides null.

I don't know any good reference about conformal diagrams in cosmology, except this one: https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.01084.  About the deSitter tilting glueing, I mean the whole deSitter diagram get rotated by 45 degrees, then glued  on another diagram, but I don't know if it really makes any sense.

About the rectangular diagram for matter and $k = 1$, if you want to keep all the light cones unchanged at 45 degrees, you do have an height 2 times the one for the radiation universe.  It is well known that light has time to reach the opposite point in closed space only once in the radiation universe, while it has time to get back at the emitter in the closed dust matter universe.
